# Vim Commands and mapping

Tags: vim

Hi I am trying to make a VIM mapping to run a script when I press F2.
I am struggle to get a full path for the file that is being edited with vim into the command function.

```
nnoremap <F2> :! php /home/kbuczynski/diff_re.php fix <full file path here> flagArg
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the full path to the current buffer with:

```
expand('%:p')
```

Your mapping could look something like this (you will also need to use the `execute` function):

```
function! CallPHP()
    execute '!php /home/kbuczynski/diff_re.php fix '.expand('%:p').' flagArg'
endfunction
nnoremap <F2> :call CallPHP()<CR>
```

[Here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/40.html) is some good documentation on dealing with file paths.

Comment: yeah i can see this is working but it does this for some reason
php /home/kbuczynski/diff_re.php fix expand('/home/file.php') flagArg
which causes the script not to run

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `:execute` and `expand()` if you have no other variable to inject. You should be able to use `%:p` directly.

```
nnoremap <F2> :!php /home/kbuczynski/diff_re.php fix %:p flagArg<cr>
```

If you need to read `flagArg` somewhere else, well, then you'll need `:execute`.